# HTML <Input> button moves to next line unexpectedly

Tags: html, css

I have a page where I am displaying the results of a search and putting a button next to each result. However the outcome is Fig 1 with the buttons below the text, when I would like Fig 2 with the buttons in line with the text. Why is this happening?

[image]

**HTML**

```
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlresult))
{
echo $row['personName'];
?>
<form action="http://website/delPerson.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" class="deleteButton">
</form>
<br>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you have any element containing this? Maybe his width is too small

Comment: I'm no UI expert but I'd start by wrapping the label/button in a div

Comment: No div just yet but width is definitely enough - thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `form` around the `input` tag, obviously it has to be like that which is a block level element, so you need to use

```
form {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

This will retain the `block` behavior of your `form` as well, but will be inline.

---

Also, the selector I've used is a general element selector, so make sure you assign a `class` to your `form` element else the selector I provided will make all your `form` to `inline-block`

So it will be like

```
form.class_name {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6NW95/)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the CSS

```
whitespace: no-wrap;
```

on the class deleteButton.

But I think the best solution is previously suggested CSS

```
display: inline-block;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `display:inline` to your form:

```
form{
    display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlresult))
    {
 ?>

        <form action="http://website/delPerson.php" method="post">
        <label> <?php echo $row['personName']; ?></label><input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" class="deleteButton"></td></tr>
        </form>


    <br>
    <?php
    }
    ?>

try this
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlresult)) {?>
 <form action="http://website/delPerson.php" method="post">
 <?php echo $row['personName'];?>
 <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" class="deleteButton">
  </form>
<br>
<?php } ?>
```